# What is a good strategy to support this deck?

Tags: deck, support

I am planning a potential DIY job for a new deck that I want to put on my house.  This is roughly what I think we want

[image]

The house is roughly 36' long and the garage roughly 22'.  The door from the house is actually only about 15-16' from the outside corner and I want the deck to come about 11' down the back before the stairs come down from there.

The door is on the first level of the home above the rear exposed basement wall, so roughly 1 story high.  The house sits on a hill that slightly grades upwards towards the garage at roughly a 12/3 pitch, so the stairs will only be a half flight.

I am variable on how far outwards roughly I am comfortable with the deck extending from the house.

My question is, what would be the optimum layout for posts and beams to properly support this deck?  (Assuming that edges of the deck touching the building will be bolted to ledger boards)  I have built a simple square deck before but never anything with outside and inside corners and variable length.

Comment: Design-wise (both aesthetics and engineering) I'd maybe consider not having that inside corner and just extending the deck out so it's all even.

Comment: @DA01 That is a good consideration actually, it might make everything more structurally sound... I wonder though how far of a joist span would be acceptable beam to ledger board?

Comment: That depends on the dimensions and type of lumber of your joist.

Comment: @decker Definitely 6x6 posts and tripled 2x12's for the beam.  Joists are probably going to be 2x10, all wolmerized dimensional lumber

Comment: 3-2x12 beam you can easily up your post spacing to at least 12'

Comment: @decker I always like to overkill when it comes to supporting a structure... plus I have a lot of obese friends ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Blue Dashed Line:** Your 3-2x12 Beam

**RED X:** 6x6 Posts

[image: Deck with beams and posts]

- D.Fir 2x10 @ 16" O.C. spanning 14' + 2' overhang past beam: **16' joists**
- Solid 2x10 Blocking mid-span
- 6x6 posts @ 12' O.C.

**post edited to match additional info from comments.*

Comment: How long do you think is too far for a single beam?  What is an acceptable joist span length in your opinion?

Comment: Depends on type/species of wood. Do you know what type of lumber is the most commonly used for pressure-treated in your area?

Comment: Typical kiln dried and wolmerized Douglas Fir, standard dimensional lumber size.

Comment: I didn't think blocking was an option :)  So I suppose tripled 2x12's down the whole length with proper 6x6 post spacing wouldn't be a problem either?  If I stagger them of course.

Comment: http://www.hobart-wi.org/vertical/sites/%7B354A483F-042E-454E-A570-720BFEDE46D9%7D/uploads/Deck_Joist__Beam_Span_Chart.pdf

Comment: sounds good: here is a triple 2x12 beam I did that was around 100' long: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-mVe7iy0QUzs/TytZuU3qDyI/AAAAAAAADHQ/bYx2SmT-cBU/s912/IMG_20120202_144634.jpg

Comment: @decker good God man... wth were you building?!

Comment: A deck :D https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5O7QJYNL-yU/Tzs34gAO3UI/AAAAAAAADNY/BxeMUXmcIJ4/s912/20120213_154036.jpg