# How can I attach a ledger board to my house?

Tags: deck, code-compliance, joists

Spring is here so I finally started to take measurements for materials I will need to build a new deck on my recently constructed home. I just realized that this isn't going to be quite so simple as I originally planned.

My house was constructed with engineered I beams and what I believe is an engineered OSB rim joist perpendicular to those (looking from the back of the house). Knowing this I knew that lag screws or even carriage bolts to hold a ledger board would not be sufficient.  Upon my own research it seemed the accepted way to handle this is to take a piece of 2 by into the inside of the I of the joist, and run a carriage bolt, through the ledger board, sheathing, rim joist and finally the added block, and to do this twice, staggered and 16" OC for each joist after that.

My father-in-law who has built several decks and is critical to this DIY project refuses to do this and he has his reasons which I respect and won't get into.

A better plan in his opinion would be something similar to what is described [in this article](http://joneakes.com/jons-fixit-database/1224-Attaching-a-deck-to-a-house)

In the old days when he built decks with his dad, they used to lag and anchor ledger boards to the concrete foundation and then toenail the joists on top. They apparently make special ties now for this purpose that is an improvement on the old toe-nail method. It seems like a much better idea and if I use 2x10 or 2x12 joists then the deck will be pretty much at the bottom of the kitchen door where it needs to be.

**Question 1: I assume that if these clips are still being produced that it must be code assuming proper lag screws and spacing have secured the ledger board?**

My second complication... assuming I go this route, only 1 deck ledger board will be attached to a poured concrete wall (the garage).  The very back of the house is actually not a poured foundation wall but a 2x6 framed exterior wall with sheathing, and a decorative stone masonry product.

**Question 2: If I were to cut away the masonry and lag into the 2x6 studs for the ledger support, would this be a sturdy code compliant ledger board?**

And finally, if applicable, if I were to cut away the masonry to mount a ledger board, I would be worried about water possibly penetrating and getting behind the decorative masonry.

**Question 3: What is the most appropriate way to prevent water from getting behind my ledger board or the masonry?**

Here is a link to my previous question for a quick diagram of the current plan:

[What is a good strategy to support this deck?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25243/what-is-a-good-strategy-to-support-this-deck)

I am feeling a bit overwhelmed and my father in law thinks I am insane for even considering calling the local code guy (he has had some bad experiences with this guy in the past over a septic system and he is convinced the guy is a sadistic monster who likes for people to spend absurd amounts of money on frivolous things).  If I can't find a clear cut answer then I will probably just hire somebody to do this because the aggravation this is causing me is not worth it.

**EDIT**

On request here is what the back of the house looks like, to the right not in view is the garage.  This is not in a seismically active area.

[image]

Comment: You have a few options here, all IRC compliant. I am a bit confused by the different faces you want to secure to. The house rim joist, the knee wall and/or garage.  Can you attach a couple of pics of the surfaces and a sketch of the relationship of the deck to the existing structures? I am also questioning the rim joist of the house. In most cases, the rim joist is solid, even if you have I-beam floor joists setting on the sill plates. Check them carefully from the inside. Once we solve the initial rim joist attachment, the rest will be easy for you with readily available hardware.

Comment: @shirlockhomes My father in law will refuse to help me if I try to go through the rim joist. Are one of the IRC compliant options setting the deck ledger board below the rim joist and setting joists on top the ledger with special ties? One second on the picture...

Comment: vinyl or cedar siding?

Comment: Since there are no rules that say the weight MUST be bourn on the rim joist against the structure, I'm toying with some ideas of adding an extra post and beam close to the house. Are you absolutely sure the house rim joist is an engineered I-beam, not solid, especially under the door?

Comment: @shirlockhomes sorry for the confusion but it is not an I joist just the same engineered osb that the I joist is made out of.  Perhaps if I doubled or tripled the ledger?

Comment: OK, I'm trying to nail this question down.  The house rim joist is a solid LAM or a mult-thickness laminated OSB? If it is at least 1.5 inches thick, like dimensional lumber, then you can treat it like such.

Comment: @shirlockhomes I am not sure... but I guess I will have to call the builder and find out the specs and manufacturer. The manufacturer would definitely know best. I am still not sure if you think joists on top of a ledger is a fundamentally bad idea or not, I imagine you think it is a bad idea or you wouldn't be exploring every other conceivable option.

Comment: As Shirlock has already suggested I would add a row of posts close to the house to carry the support beam for the deck. This solves many many problems with cutting into the house structure and dealing with environmental sealing issues. If you do this make sure to add triangulation members make the deck assembly strong and eliminate scissoring and sway. With such construction you can probably limit your connection to the house to just the short area under the patio door in the area that already setup for that purpose (I note the differing material there in the picture).

Comment: What ever you decide to do make sure that you draw a nice set of plans and submit them with your building permit application for local agency approval.

Comment: @MichaelKaras That seems far more expensive and time consuming, especially since this new construction and the ground is disturbed near the house.  I would have to dig down VERY FAR.  It seems that everybody is bound and determined to make this more complicated and expensive than it needs to be, so I am just going to pay somebody else to do this. Thank for the load of disappointment.

Comment: Your choice of course. I just gave my idea. When you consider the total cost of decent materials for a deck the addition of an extra row of posts would be a small addition. The support beam that you would attach to them is already what you are talking about trying to mount to the house structure. It also appears that you live in a winter freeze zone so you already need to consider deep footings to support the deck posts. These could probably just be round holes with the thick cardboard tube forms filled up with concrete. Just dig down to the level that the house footings were placed.

Comment: @ Maple:  Maybe we could meet on chat.  Then we can have a much quicker exchange.  I really don't think it is gonna be as complicated as it may sound. I have build over a hundred decks and yet to see one that couldn't be attached or supported. I look or a pic of the joist box ends from inside could settle the question. As I said earlier, I have never seen anything but some sort of solid rims setting on a sill or top plates of knee walls.

Comment: AS you asked earlier, joists resting on top of a ledger beam are perfectly fine. The real question here is where to attach the beam. Doesn't make any difference where the joists sit, there is hardware that works for either method.

Comment: Honestly, it appears the easiest and most affordable solution is reinforcing the engineered rim and remove siding as necessary and attaching the ledger just below the finish deck level, allowing for decking thickness. Hang the deck joists from the ledger with joist hangers. You father in law objects to spending money on frivolous requirements, yet this is exactly what he is asking you to do. Anything other than this approach is going to cost you more money, solely because he has an irrational objection to this legitimate approach.

Comment: you need some adjustable scaffold feet!

Comment: @decker I didn't set up the scaffolding in this picture, this was the work of the masonry subcontractor while the house was still being built. They were all Mexican, probably here illegally, and probably didn't have any kind of insurance if they would have gotten hurt to make matters even worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off let me quote the American Wood Council [PRESCRIPTIVE RESIDENTIAL WOOD DECK CONSTRUCTION GUIDE](http://www.awc.org/publications/DCA/DCA6/DCA6-09.pdf) (which I recommend looking through).

> **MANUFACTURED WOOD I-JOIST:** Many new homes constructed with wood I-joists include 1" or thicker engineered wood products (EWP) – such
>   as oriented strand board (OSB) or structural composite lumber (SCL)
>   including laminated veneer lumber (LVL) – as band joists (or rim
>   boards) that can support the attachment of a deck.
>   However, some older homes might be constructed with band boards that
>   are too thin (less than 1") to support a deck. In such cases, a
>   free-standing deck or a full plan submission is required.

You asked:

> ***Question 1: I assume that if these clips are still being produced that it must be code assuming proper lag screws and spacing have secured the ledger board?***

Yes.

It doesn't matter how the joists have bearing, whether it is a hanger, ledger, or beam. Just use the appropriate hardware/fasteners for the application.

[image: Joist-to-beam connection]

> ***Question 2: If I were to cut away the masonry and lag into the 2x6
>   studs for the ledger support, would this be a sturdy code compliant
>   ledger board?***

Back in the "good old days" when homes were [balloon-framed](http://oikos.com/esb/27/balloon_framing.html) they would use let-in ledgers or ribbon boards to support the floor framing (which was also nailed to the studs, though). So, it is doable, but you may need special permission or even engineer's drawings/specs for approval (might also include blocking and extra hardware). Either way, I would say it is not exactly ideal, but at least you could use structural screws like [Ledgerlok](http://www.fastenmaster.com/details/product/ledgerlok-ledger-board-fastener.html)s or [GRK](http://www.grkfasteners.com/index.php/en/products/rss/rss-rugged)s, since they are smaller diameter and self-drilling and not nearly as likely to split the studs.

[image: Balloon Framed, Ribbon Board w/ fire blocking]

(balloon-framed, ribbon-board (ledger) and fire-blocking)

[image: LedgerLOK]

> ***And finally, if applicable, if I were to cut away the masonry to mount
>   a ledger board, I would be worried about water possibly penetrating
>   and getting behind the decorative masonry.***

You would have the same worries doing the same thing when cutting out siding for a ledger. Flashing to the rescue :)

> ***Question 3: What is the most appropriate way to prevent water from
>   getting behind my ledger board or the masonry?***

Again, flashing is the most important part (aside from proper fastening). You have to lap the flashing properly with the building paper. Just remember the direction water flows so the surfaces have to lap the same way a shingle would. See image below for a good illustration of proper flashing. You can also read [this short article](http://www.finehomebuilding.com/tool-guide/departments/what-is-the-difference/ledger-flashing.aspx) describing some of the flashing material choices.

[image: Ledger Flashing]

After all that, I would say your best bet is to verify your rim board thickness and do a normal ledger. The second best option is a free-standing deck.

Just be careful there is a lot of bad advice and information on the internet!

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer! I worried about splitting studs as well but this laglok product seems good for this.

Comment: Sorry, I posted this late last night and looking at it again with fresh eyes, the balloon frame image is using a ribbon-board and not a let-in ledger as I had it originally labeled. So don't go around calling that a let-in ledger when it is really a ribbon-board! Also I added an image of joist-bearing options.

Comment: So I guess then it is still considered acceptable to toenail joists in?  I personally would feel more comfortable with hurricane clips or other strong ties.  Delays in the landscaping mean that I won't be able to start this project until probably summer, but I should get a chance to talk with my old project manager about the type of rim board used (manufacturer, thickness, etc...) to determine my options.  It will be a month or two but I will be sure to report back and let you know what I find out.

Comment: toenailing is acceptable when the deck is attached to the house (and probably with traditional ledger). I assume this is so all the joists don't roll over in the same direction. You can prevent that with toenailing + solid blocking, but really it is better and easier to just use the hurricane ties like you figured.

Comment: Also, if you consider the free-standing route and are worried about footing depth due to this being a new construction, you might want to check these bad boys out: http://www.pinfoundations.com due to it being a new construction you might know what is in the ground and not as worried about hitting large rocks or boulders.

Comment: Just thought I would update with new information after talking with the PM.  He said it is 1 1/4" engineered rim and acceptable for mounting a ledger board to. If his crew were building the deck they would stagger in a W formation with every top fastener being a carriage bolt and every bottom fastener being a lag screw going into the sill and they would space them apart every 16".  He said that all the local code enforcers in this region find this more than acceptable.

Comment: Great news! Although you can't carriage bolt unless you have access to the back of the rim from the inside, i.e. cut open the drywall if it is finished interior space. You could ask the inspector to "okay" lags or ledgerlok-type screws.