# Should I use silicone caulk on the side of a deck ledger?

Tags: deck, flashing, silicone, ledger

I have a deck ledger attached to the rim joist (the vinyl siding was cut away), and some flashing above the ledger.  On the side of the ledger there is a gap between the end of the 2x10, and the siding.  I was going to put a [j-channel trim piece](http://www.lowes.com/pd_6550-46086-329063_0__?productId=3037104&Ntt=j+channel&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Dj%2Bchannel&facetInfo=) on the siding:

[image]

I would then use silicone caulk to basically fill in the space between the edge of the vinyl and the ledger so water can't make it in there. Is this a good idea?

I can't seem to find much information about how to flash the end of the ledger.  [One post here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30242/ledger-flashing-on-the-sides) didn't quite cover how to fill in a 1/4 to 1/2 in gap.

Also I was going to caulk the nails on the joist hangers, they had to be 3 inches long so they went through the house wrap.

Comment: How is this question any different than the one you linked to?  Did you read the answer on the linked question?

Answer (score 1):

You are always going to get some water behind the vinyl siding that is what the housewrap is for.  You can caulk the sides if you want too but its not necessary. Water that makes it to the inside of the j channel will also get behind the siding.